# How to prevent images from resizing when adding text within a horizontal media scroller?

Tags: css, media, image-size

[image]

When creating a horizontal media scroller to scroll through a group of images on every mouse click, I've noticed when adding text below the image tags it resizes the image.

As text in the paragraph tags increase the images gets resized even though all the images have the same dimensions. How would I achieve a responsive layout (regardless of the amount of text in the paragraph tag) that maintains the shrinking and scaling of all the images uniformly as the user resizes the browser. Adding more text to the paragraph tags should increase the height of the container and not it's width.

Please note that if I do not include paragraph tags the images maintain their proportion when the browser is resized. Please refer to the screen shot. Thankyou

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
.media-scroller {
  margin: 0 14rem;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: grid;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-auto-columns: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overscroll-behavior-inline: contain;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.group {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
.media-element {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: min-content;
  gap: 0.8rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.snaps-inline {
  scroll-snap-type: inline mandatory;
  scroll-padding-inline: 0.3rem;
}
.snaps-inline > * {
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
p {
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #5799ef;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  background-color: #2c2c2c;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="media-scroller snaps-inline">
      <div class="group">
        <div class="media-element">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/05/00/03/cat-5627808__340.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <p class="title">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellat
            adipisci molestiae rerum sint. Accusantium, expedita! Numquam
            recusandae iste omnis deserunt.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="media-element">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/11/09/16/56/cat-6781934__340.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="media-element">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/08/06/06/41/cat-6525495__340.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit adipisicing elit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="group">
        <div class="media-element">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/09/25/19/22/animal-6655641__340.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <p class="title">Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="media-element">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/11/14/19/20/kittens-1824367__340.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="media-element">
          <img
            src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/07/15/10/10/cat-6468024__340.jpg"
            alt=""
          />
          <p class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: 'even though the imgs are the same size' - but you've set the img size to 100% width and the width of the cell is determined by its content and as that varies so do the dimensions of the image. What do you want it to look like? Should each grid item be the same width as well as the same height?

Comment: Yes. I would like all the images to shrink and scale uniformly as the user resizes the browser. I want this to happen with the paragraph tags beneath them regardless of the word count. Disregard the values I've given selectors as I'm seeking what values to target.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you put your `img` and `p` in the same `div`. You should create a seperate `div` for your `img` and `p` inside your media element `div`. That way you get more flexibility in styling. You can learn more about flexbox [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Comment: Already went down that path with flexbox /grid to no avail. If I had to start listing the trials and errors I went through before posting the year would be over and done with.